# Change Git commiter in Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans

In Netbeans 7.1 Git support has been added, however, I don't see a way to change commiter information. Currently, it's defaulting to my system information which is not what I want. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try setting it in the local gitconfig file `.git/config`:

```
[user]
        name = yourname
        email = youremail
```

Comment: For me the file was located at `~/.gitconfig`. (Netbeans 7.1 on Windows)  Worked like a charm.

Comment: thanks again, this just prevent my from getting a lot of stress ! netbeans just submitted my real name and very private email due to this.

Comment: @MikeS. .gitconfig on Windows 7 wasn't recognized by NetBeans 8.0.1

Comment: In NetBeans 8.0.x this file can be accessed via Team > Repository > Open Config OR Right-click Menu > Git > Repository > Open Config

Comment: @Dazed I think Global Config

Answer (score 19):

You can just edit the default text in the combo boxes and NetBeans will remember it for next time. The data is saved in a `git.properties` file, for example: 
`C:\Users\USERNAME\.netbeans\7.1.2\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\git.properties`).

**EDIT:**

As per the below comment, it seems that the config file's location changed in NetBeans 8 (I don't use NetBeans for a long time already).

Here's an alternative location according to @tzi:
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Netbeans\8.0.1\config\Preferences\org\netbean‌​s\modules\git.properties`

Comment: With NetBeans 8.0.1 it didn't use this as default, just for the drop-down

Comment: it was `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Netbeans\8.0.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\git.properties` for me

Comment: For Netbeans 8.2 in macOS User directory: `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.2/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/git.properties`or Using Netbeans About **User directory:** beginning path.

Answer (score 7):

this helped me:
https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user

Configuring git

To check your git setting, run this command:

```
git config user.email
# you@there.com
```

If this email is not correct, you can change the global setting:

```
git config --global user.email "me@here.com"
```

Comment: Cool!!!
It is also good to put the form to change the username. follows: 

git config user.name --global "john.legend"

Answer (score 2):

it worked in netbeans v7.3.1/windows 7 by adding those entries

name = github user name

email = github registered email

in file

C:\Users\[USER NAME]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\git.properties

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 file location:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\.gitconfig
```

Comment: and you should do what with this file?

Comment: see the sibling comments; http://stackoverflow.com/a/8803742/107282 | http://stackoverflow.com/a/8803752/107282

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/2_setup_and_initialization.html).

It will work unless what you are trying to achieve is to have two sets of committer information on the OS same user account.

From the page:

```
[user]
    name = Scott Chacon
    email = schacon@gmail.com
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if quotation was required. Thanks for the example