# Change GitHub Contributor in NetBeans 7.2.1

Tags: netbeans, github, netbeans-7.2

I was hoping that someone could help me figure out where the option to change / add a contributor to my netbeans 7.2.1 for github. I have seen online places and questions for 7.1.2 but those did not work for me.

[Change Git commiter in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803714/change-git-commiter-in-netbeans)

I had netbeans set up properly on my windows 8 computer. One day I decided to separate my computer into two users. One for work and one for play (less distractions). Unfortunately when I did this and set up my github in netbeans it now told me that I was now Guest_2 (The old name of the windows user account).

I have looked in templates which it seems to be where most answers lead me to but I don't have the options in Options that they have in their answers. I tried modifying Git.properties and just adding name=(my git hub name) and on another line email=(my git hub email) but it still just sends my commits as Guest_2.

I have tried going to Tools>Options>Miscellaneous>Versioning> General & Git but neither one has anything I could see about changing author/contributor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated for I know I'm just tired and that I've overlooked something very simple.

Comment: Have you tried to simply overwrite the name in the commit-window?

Comment: It replaces the name but it does not associate it with my account.